# Instagram API doesn't give me code for OAUTH request

Tags: php, instagram-api

I'm trying to make a request to new Instagram API following [Official Instagram API guide](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

```
<?php
     $client_id = '...';
     $client_secret = '...';
     $redirect_uri = '...';

     $urlCode = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=$client_id&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&response_type=code";

     $code = $_GET["code"];
     echo $code;

     /*CURL REQUEST*/
     .................
?>
```

But nothing is printed, what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: How is this particular script getting accessed? From a page? Can you give an example of the URL if applicable?

Comment: Yes from a page, my idea is to call the .php from browser. Unfortunately is a private host for now so i can't give URL.
The link in $urlCode should answer in GET the code and it works if i paste in the browser bar

Comment: You need to send the users to the URL and then they will be redirected back to your page with an authentification code as a GET parameter. Are you doing so?

Comment: This might also help you (so you don't start from scratch): https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API